# Given $f(A) = \{ac \mid abc \in A \ and \ |a| = |b| = |c|\}$, why is $f(L)$ not regular if $L$ is a regular language?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata, regular-language

Given the function:

$$f(A) = \{ac \mid abc \in A \ and \ |a| = |b| = |c|\}$$

Why is $f(L)$ not always regular if $L$ is a regular language?

Is pumping lemma useful in this situation?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know. Since comments are easily overlooked, please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3392640/edit) to make any additions and/or clarifications.

Comment: Do you mean "why is $f(L)$ not _always_ regular"? Unless I'm misunderstanding, you can sometimes get a regular language out, eg $f(\{a\}^*) = \{a\}^*$.

Comment: @NicholasViggiano I think that's the question, looks like I have omitted some important info.

Comment: In that case it suffices to find a counterexample. Poke around at some of your favorite regular languages until you find one whose collapse isn't regular (and yes, you'll probably have to use the pumping lemma to prove that bit).

Comment: See [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29382/find-a-regular-language-that-becomes-non-regular-if-you-cut-away-the-middle-thir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I will use different notation from yours.

**Hint**. Let $A = \{a,b,c\}$ be the alphabet and let $L = a^*cb^*$. Compute the language $f(L) \cap a^*b^*$ and show that it is not regular.

Comment: Why do we need to intersect $f(L)$ with $a^*b^*$

Comment: Because it is simpler to compute $f(L) \cap a^*b^*$ than $f(L)$.

Comment: I don't understand what we are trying to do... So, since according to the function, string should have at least length of $3r$ where  $r \geq 0$, $f(L)$ is going to be $a^xcb^y$ where $x + 1 + y = 3r$ with $1/3rd$(middle part) of the string removed. Intersecting it with $a^*b^*$ should be an emptyset because there's no $c$ in $a^*b^*$?

Comment: If $L = \{acb\}$, what is $f(L)$?

Comment: Assuming $abc$ is a string in $L$, $f(L)$ would be $ab$.

Comment: What do we need to do with $ab$ though? Since $ab \cap a^*b^* = ab$, why is this not regular?

Comment: I just gave this example to convince you that the intersection was not empty, as you claimed. Now, reconsider my hint and compute the suggested intersection correctly.

Comment: Hmm, so $f(L) \cap a^*b^* = \{ a^nb^n \mid n \geq 0\}$ which is not regular? What does thar mean though?